# Complementary channel of convex combination of channels

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, duality

Consider two channels $N_1$ and $N_2$ which have Kraus operators $\{A_k\}$ and $\{B_k\}$ respectively, where the index $k$ runs over the number of Kraus operators. Define a third channel $N$ as a convex combination of $N_1$ and $N_2$. Specifically, for $0\leq p \leq 1$

$$N(\rho) = pN_1(\rho) + (1-p)N_2(\rho)$$

The Kraus operators corresponding to $N$ are $\{\sqrt{p}A_k\}\cup\{\sqrt{1-p}B_k\}$.

I would now like to look at the complementary channel of these channels. We have

$$N_1^c(\rho) = \sum_{k,j}\text{Tr}(A_k\rho A_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert$$

$$N_2^c(\rho) = \sum_{k,j}\text{Tr}(B_k\rho B_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert$$

The channel $N$ however picks up some cross terms when I work out the complemetary channel.
\begin{align}
N^c(\rho) &= \sum_{k,j}p\text{Tr}(A_k\rho A_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert + \sum_{k,j}\sqrt{p(1-p)}\text{Tr}(A_k\rho B_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert \\
&+ \sum_{k,j}\sqrt{p(1-p)}\text{Tr}(B_k\rho A_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert + \sum_{k,j}(1-p)\text{Tr}(B_k\rho B_j^\dagger)\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert
\end{align}

What is a bit weird is if I now let $N_1 = N_2 = N$. Then, obviously $N_1^c = N_2^c = N^c$. However, the "cross terms" in the expression above seem like extra terms after setting all the $B_k = A_k$. It does not seem that they go to zero. What is the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one error.

First, for the complementary channel you need to attach a state (the $\otimes \vert k\rangle\langle j\vert$ in your formulas) for *every* possible Kraus operators. Your new channel has twice as many Kraus operators, therefore, you need an extra label for that degree of freedom.

What you then get for $N_1=N_2$ (with identical Kraus operators) however still has these cross-terms, just with the extra label.

Here comes the second error: The complementary channel is not uniquely defined.  It is rather only defined up to basis transformations of the dual system.  The cross-terms are exactly necessary to un-rotate the two-copy representation of $N^c$ with operators $A$ and $B$ to the original version.  Without those cross-terms, the map would actually go onto that bigger space, and a rotation on the original $N^c$ would not be possible.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but to rephrase what you have said, there exists an isometry on the dual space between the two expressions I have (once the range over which $k$ and $j$ run is corrected).

Comment: @user1936752 Precisely.  (Basically, if $A_k=B_k$ then all four coefficients in your (cross-)terms will be equal for AA and AB and BB pairs; and the additional "tag" you add to the label $k$ should be exactly in a |+> state.)